# Convert Delphi Bitwise Operation to Cobol

Tags: delphi, cobol, bitwise-operators

How can this code be converted to COBOL?

```
Result := GetSysColor(Color and $000000FF)
```

The value types are DWORD, I guess it is a bitwise operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a bitwise operation, however, this specifically operation is equivalent to

```
COMPUTE Result = Color mod 256.
```

Or

```
COMPUTE Result = MOD(Color, 256).
```

If I remember my COBOL correctly. It has been <strike>decades</strike> years since I worte a line of COBOL.

Comment: The COBOL 85 standard has no mod operator.  Use the MOD function instead with RESULT = MOD(Color,256)